# update nginx status code

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

I want nginx to handle 404 error status and redirect them to another domain.

In headers "Location:" is updated but status is still 404 but should be 301.

Here is my code :

```
# error handling
error_page 404 @404;
log_not_found off;
proxy_intercept_errors on;
```

and :

```
location @404 {
  rewrite ^ http://www.example.com/404.html? permanent;
}
```

So following command `lynx -head -dump 'http://localhost:9999/a_404_error'` gives me :

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/0.8.54
Date: Mon, 11 Apr 2011 18:59:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: close
Location: http://www.example.com/404.html
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

I finally did it like this :

```
error_page 404 http://www.example.com/404.html
```

It gives a 302 code and just works

Answer (score 1):

error_page 404 = @404 will allow location @404 to set the response status

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: You're sure you included the =, and you reloaded your config?  I just tested it and it worked fine for me.